# Calculating Time elapsed for ten users at the same time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, stopwatch

I need to capture the time taken between two button press of ten users.
I am doing like this with `StopWatch`.

```
Stopwatch stopwatch1;  
Stopwatch stopwatch2;
```

........ Like this ten stop watches.

```
private void Start_Action1()  
{   
   stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();  
   stopwatch1.Start();  
}  
private void Stop_Action1()  
{   
   stopwatch1.Stop();   
   txtTimeForAction1.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();  
}
```

Same code for 10 StopWatches.
NOTE: All the users will do this START-STOP action continuously. I need to record time-elapsed for each cycle separately.  I am using in desktop application. All the users will use the same application.

Using 10 `Stopwatch` is good practice?? Is there any better way than this?

Comment: I am not sure in what scenario you are using it, ASP.NET or Desktop/mobile app? In any case probably all user have their own instance of application working and hence single stopwatch will work for all. Please clarify the need more.

Comment: I am using in desktop application. All the users will use the same application.

Comment: even if you are using same application, probably one user is working at a time, because you cannot get 10 mouse or keyboard. Right ? If so then you might have a switch of user in application at this time just re-init your watch and store the result at end in some file/db/memory. IF you still think the user are working simultaneously on same machine, then take List/Array and store update with events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd give each "user" a DateTime (StartTime) and then when the event has finished (So E.g. Key_Up) You can get the Elapsed time with:

```
DateTime elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - StartTime.
```

then use elapsedTime.Seconds or .Minutes etc. and even use elpasedTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss") to get a nicely formatted string.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep track of the starting times for every user, use one stopwatch and don't stop it after the stop action is called by one user, only when they have all stopped. I don't know if it's better practice, but it is a different way to do it.

Comment: Just start your stopwatch. Then instead of starting and stopping it every time you keep the times in variables (plain ints, arrays or lists, whatever suits you)

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why not using stop watches. But instead of defining ten stop watches you should save them in an array or in a dictionary where each `StopWatch` is associated with a user.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. I just want to know about usage of system resource wise any better approach is there..